# Trying to read a file on the sdCard to a variable

Tags: java, android, file, filereader, file-read

I have this function and when I call it, it won't return anything.

```
public String getfileFromSDCard(String filename){//get the file
    String text;
    text = "";

    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(root,"file.txt");
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String str;

        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text = text + str;
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return text;
}
```

Do I need to add any permission to my android manifiest other than

...uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" ... ( I worte this line right in the code)

I have this one added already and running cause I can easily write a file, but I cant read it afterward

This is how I'm calling the function from the onCreate

```
    TextView countDisplay = new TextView(this);
    CreatefiletoSDCard("testnumberone.txt","22222fkdf sdjf hjsdf sdj fsdf ");
    countDisplay.setText(getfileFromSDCard("testnumberone.txt"));

    this.setContentView(countDisplay);
```

ps: CreatefiletoSDCard() works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you pass in a `filename` parameter in your `getfileFromSDCard()` method, you seem to have hardcoded the actual file(name) you're reading from to `file.txt`. Guessing by the filenames you use for creating your test files, the error is probably that you're trying to read from a non-existent file, no matter what name you actually pass into the method.

In other words, you probably want to change the following line:

```
File file = new File(root,"file.txt");
```

to:

```
File file = new File(root,filename);
```